# rails routing nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

I have next resources

```
 resources :countries do
    resources :cities
 end    

 resources :cities do
    resources :streets
 end
```

it generates next routes

```
GET    /countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)                          cities#index
POST   /countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)                          cities#create
new_country_city GET    /countries/:country_id/cities/new(.:format)                      cities#new
edit_country_city GET    /countries/:country_id/cities/:id/edit(.:format)                 cities#edit
GET    /countries/:country_id/cities/:id(.:format)                      cities#show
PUT    /countries/:country_id/cities/:id(.:format)                      cities#update
DELETE /countries/:country_id/cities/:id(.:format)                      cities#destroy


......
cities GET    /cities(.:format)                                                cities#index
POST   /cities(.:format)                                                cities#create
new_city GET    /cities/new(.:format)                                            cities#new
edit_city GET    /cities/:id/edit(.:format)                                       cities#edit
city GET    /cities/:id(.:format)                                            cities#show
PUT    /cities/:id(.:format)                                            cities#update
DELETE /cities/:id(.:format)                                            cities#destroy
```

I dont want access to cities can be without country id but also I don't want to use  3-levels nested resources, so I can change routes like next

```
 resources :countries do
        resources :cities
     end    

     resources :cities, :except => [:index, :destroy, :edit, :show, :create, :new, :update] do
        resources :streets
     end
```

Is there some kind of shortcut to disable all action instead of write all default actions at :except option ????

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
resources :cities, :only => [] do
    ...
end
```

Comment: In Rails 2.2, you could do `:except => :all` but that does no longer work. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this routes

```
  resources :topics do
    resources :solutions
  end

  resources :solutions, only: [] do
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
  end
```